# iPhone pushNotification DeviceToken - How to "decrypt"

Tags: php, iphone, encoding, nsdata, push-notification

I've already managed to get the devicetoken from APNs. It's type of NSData.
So i want to write this deviectoken into my mysql db.
I've already tried to convert it to a string without luck.
That was my way:

```
 NSString *tokenTMP = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:devToken encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

If i have the deviceToken in a readable format. How do i use the token in php to send a request to the apns server?

thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I added the following category to NSData

```
- (NSString*) stringWithHexBytes 
{
   NSMutableString *stringBuffer = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:([self length] * 2)];
   const unsigned char *dataBuffer = [self bytes];

   for (int i = 0; i < [self length]; ++i)
   {
       [stringBuffer appendFormat:@"%02X", (unsigned long)dataBuffer[ i ]];
   }

   return [[stringBuffer retain] autorelease];
}
```

Then I can just call [devToken stringWithHexBytes]; and send that up to my server and store it as text.

Hope that helps.

chris.

Comment: thanks for the help.
If i want run the app, the compiler complains about
([self length] * 2) the error
"invalid operands to binary * (have 'id' and 'int')"
occurs.

Comment: I've edited your function, now it works! thanks a lot!

- (NSString*) stringWithHexBytes:(NSData *)token;
Works like charme :)